# osx - cannot open images or pdfs

Tags: macos, preview

When I try to open images or pdfs with preview, the application starts but the files never open. When I try to open them from the command line, I get the error message:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -1712 for file [...]
```

This was working yesterday, so presumably I did something to break it since then, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it could have been.

Comment: Try opening the pdf with adobe reader, and images with something else (using the Open with..) to narrow it down to preview it self. For example use the space bar to open in Quick View.

Answer (score 1):

Were you using Firefox browser to download them?

If so in Firefox go to: Tools>Add-ons>Plugins>Adobe Acrobat NPAPi Plugin>Disable.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/925055?e=es&as=aaq

---

If not then right click (control click) on a PDF file. Select "get info". Toward the bottom of the dialog you'll see "Open with:" and an arrow. Click on the arrow and you'll be presented with the applications that can open PDF files. Select Preview and then click on the box that says: "Change All..."

When you select Preview it will say below it: "Use this application to open all documents like this one."

Answer (score 0):

There can be a few reasons for this to happen, but the most likely cause is a disk permissions problem.

Disk permissions are flags set for each item in the file system. They define whether an item can be read, written to, or executed.

The `LSOpenURLsWithRole` is a function that is used to associate a file with a program.

Open Disk Utility in your Utility folder and run repair permissions.